# Automatic javascript and css caching in jquery mobile? (Beginner?)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am currently working on a webapp that need to  include a lot of js file like facebook sdk, jquery, jquery mobile, etc.

I wonder is it the case that if you load all css and js files on one single page, e.g. index.php, then all subsequent pages as linked in the index page can also use the js and css files already downloaded.

I would also be grateful on any suggestion in how to manage the caching of js files in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is correct, but if the user lands on a different page other than the first, they won't have access to those files. This also only applies as long as you don't disable the Ajax navigation at any point/page/link

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply! If I include all the script and css in pages other than the index page, would the browser redownload all the script even if they had previously download it? Or is there a way to instruct the browser accordingly. Is it done through php or javascript?

Comment: I would include the file references on every page. If the user lands on `page1.html` or `any-page.html` they will download the file once, and then it will be stored in jQuery mobile's DOM and will reference from there until they clear their cache.

Comment: Is it the same for server hosted script and cdn script? So in case like this <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>, I don't need to worry about re-downloading of script even if I include this on every page? .... And if I must use rel="external" in one of my page, which would break the ajax chain in jquery mobile, e.g. index ---(via external)--> a  ----> b, when I reach b, is there still a way to use the scripts downloaded at index?

Comment: You ALWAYS want to use the CDN code! Most users probably already have it from another site they visited, so then they don't have to download it at all! Using the `external` link isn't bad... just be sure to include the script on ALL pages like I suggested. This way you're always covered and the site doesn't break. The users' browser will always use the script they already downloaded unless they clear their cache or do a full page refresh. If you're using the CDN, I would recommend using Google's: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/